# DLL load failed: The specific module could not be found (VSCode, Numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code, anaconda

Error occurs upon `import numpy as np`; command works fine when typed directly in terminal, but fails when ran via [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner). My steps to reproduce below.

Output of `import sys; print(sys.version)` is `3.7.5 (default, Oct 31 2019, 15:18:51) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]`. VSCode shows it's running the expected Python interpreter: `Python 3.7.5 64-bit ('vsc': conda)` at bottom-left pane (see clip). -- Brief [video demo](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cu4vzyp8ybdq6qo/np_demo.mp4?dl=0).

For a complete list of enabled extensions and contents of `settings.json`, see [relevant Git](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/15183).

What is the problem, and how to fix?

---

**Env info**: Windows 10 x64, Anaconda 10/19 (virtual env), VSCode 1.41.1

---

**Steps to reproduce:**

```
conda create --name vsc
conda activate vsc
conda install python==3.7.5
conda install numpy
# in VSCode: import numpy as np, etc
```

---

**Full traceback**:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\vsc\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\vsc\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\vsc\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py", line 7, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Desktop\School\Python\vscode\HelloWorld\app.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\vsc\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\vsc\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:
```

---

**EDIT**: added the following to `settings.json` per James's suggestion:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["/K", "D:\\Anaconda\\Scripts\\activate.bat D:\\Anaconda"],
"python.condaPath": "D:\\Anaconda\\Scripts\\conda.exe"
```

Comment: How did you point VSCode to the conda environment?

Comment: @James `Ctrl + Shift + P` `-> Python: Select Interpreter` `-> Python 3.7.5 64-bit ('vsc': conda)`

Answer (score 9):

Based on your comment, it looks like the conda environment is not being activated by VSCode.  Selecting the Python interpreter points VSCode to the Python executable (python.exe), but sometimes environmental variables that are set by Conda are used to tell packages with large backends where to look for the compiled binaries.

Conda does this to save on space.  If you already have the DLLs in one environment, it will sometimes link to them when creating a new environment rather than installing them again.  So the goal is to get VSCode to use Conda in the same way you would use it through the Start Menu: firing up the Anaconda Command prompt before starting Python.

In VSCode open your `settings.json` file for editing using the following operations:

```
(type)               CTRL + SHIFT + P
(search for:)        open settings
(click:)             Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)
```

We are going to add 3 lines to the JSON file.  The first tell VSCode to use a Windows integrated shell.  The second adds additional arguments when firing up the Windows Shell that run each time; this is where we will activate the base Conda environment.  (This is just copy/pasted from the Anaconda Command Prompt shortcut properties.)  The third line lets VSCode where your Conda executable is so it can properly change environments.

My Anaconda base environment is located at `C:\Anaconda3\`.  You will need to modify the paths to your installation.

```
settings.json
```

```json
{
    ... # any other settings you have already added (remove this line)

    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["/K", "C:\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\activate.bat C:\\Anaconda3"],
    "python.condaPath": "C:\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\conda.exe"
}
```

Save the file, change your interpreter to the `base` conda environment, restart VSCode, change your interpreter again to `vsc`.

Comment: Thanks for the response; followed everything, unfortunately didn't work. I also tried removing the second `C:\\...` from line 2, and also delimiting it with a comma (shouldn't there be one?) - also didn't work. On each try, I pointed interpreter to `base`, restarted VSC, then pointed again to `vsc`. Lastly, your first line was already in my `settings.json` as the very first line, so I just left it there.

Comment: Also, just like the terminal, the debugger runs [fine](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9hs7qkk6rczbpm9/np_demo2.mp4?dl=0); the problem may revolve around the code runner extension

Comment: Upvoted for the effort and ruling out a factor; opened [Issue](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/issues/576) on Code Runner git, hopefully it's resolved there

Comment: Configuring settings.json does work fine for me. Need to restart VSCode and then select conda Python interpreter again.

Comment: What is the MacOS version of those?

Comment: @Adam_G, I am sorry, but I don't own a Mac to test this on.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. In my case Anaconda3 and VS Code were installed separately. Here are the steps that worked for me to fix the problem:

- Completely uninstall VS Code including any user settings/cache and start menu entries
- Re-install VS Code from Anaconda Navigator
- Launch Anaconda Prompt and activate whichever environment I want to use through `conda activate myenv`
- Launch VS Code from Anaconda Prompt by typing `code`

It will find the `numpy` package path in your environment now.

Answer (score 2):

The answer above are being depreciated by VS Code. The more modern solution is to force VS to activate the Anaconda when running Code standalone by adding:

```
"python.condaPath": "C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\conda.exe",
"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true,
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt"
```

This has worked for me so far. Note this doesn't work with:

```
"python.terminal.launchArgs": ["-m", "IPython"],
```

So make sure that is not hidden in your settings.json.

Comment: it works for me as well

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I've fixed it by adding the `Python.CondaPath` in settings. Press `Ctrl + Shift + P` and select Terminal Configuration. Search for `python.conda`, and paste your conda path for example. C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe

This will fix your issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you deactivate the Code Runner extension and make sure you select the appropriate conda environment using the [Python extension for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) you will get a green play button instead of a white one. That green play button will use the environment you selected and thus should have numpy installed.

Comment: I'm aware, but I much prefer to run it via Code Runner or alike to hide all the terminal / execution messages that clutter the console (also IPython)