# Kernel failed to start as a dll could not be loaded

Tags: python, dll, jupyter-notebook

When trying to run any jupyter notebook script (ipynb) on VScode I get the following error:

The kernel failed to start as a dll could not be loaded.
Click here for more info.

This is using my base conda environment which has the following address:

```
~\anaconda3\python.exe
```

I made a new default environment on conda however this still resulted in the same error.

I believe it may be a PATH issue and I tried setting a system PATH to the new default environment but the same error occurred.

It must be something to do with conda because the default python that I have downloaded on my local drive is working fine.

Comment: standard download of python from the official website and a standard install of vscode also from the official website => this means that you wont need acaconda!

Comment: "It must be something to do with conda because the default python that I have downloaded on my local drive is working fine." In the future if you plan to use Anaconda/conda, I would suggest Python that comes with and that you handle with Anaconda/conda would be the only installation of Python on your system. Have you seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59519338/8508004) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58125351/8508004) and [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4332#issuecomment-502000316)?

Answer (score 0):

This error may occur because the **pyzmq** module is missing or incompatible with your Python version. I did the following steps one time and it made my code run fine.
First, open the Anaconda Prompt and activate your base environment with conda activate base. Second,  uninstall the pyzmq module with pip uninstall pyzmq.
Then reinstall the pyzmq module with pip install pyzmq==19.0.2 (last version I guess).
Finally, restart VScode and try to run your script again.
If this note didn't work for you I recommend to install the Jupyter package in your base environment with pip install **jupyter** and go through it.

Comment: I tried downgrading my pyzmp from 25.1.2 to 19.0.2 however this didn't work and raised more compatibility errors. 
I have already tried to reinstall jupyter but I ended up with the same dll error. Feel free to send any other suggestions!

Comment: You are both using Jupyter in Anaconda, and so hopefully `pip` entering the equation at all is only as a last resort. For those maybe not familiar, once you choose the Anaconda Distribution/conda as your package manager it is **your primary package manager from then on**; you'd only ideally use `pip` for installing things there's no conda recipe for and always use Anaconda/conda to do all installations. However, sometimes when things like this happen and additional install via `pip` does seem to bandaid things for Jupyter. It is not idea and points to issues that may keep compounding.